# Can I use the toolbar/app bar in multiple activities/screens without writing adding individually in each screen?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, toolbar, appbar

I am developing an app and I am using the material design app bar and I want to use that single toolbar/app bar which I have declared in the main activity to each activity in my app.

Comment: one activity, different fragments, toolbar in the activity. so yes

Comment: What do you mean by "without writing adding individually in each screen?" and "I want to use that single toolbar/app bar which I have declared in the main activity to each activity in my app"? Do you mean that you want the bar to appear in each activity, but it can get its own copy of the bar? If so, you could use inheritance, with a base activity class that defines the bar and that your other activities extend. If, instead, you mean that you want a single bar, and that changing screens changes what is under the bar, do not use multiple activities. Use fragments or composables instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify whether you need a toolbar or not in your styles.xml file

```
<style name="MaterialAppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```